Pixel-Perfect Collision Detection Issue in Kivy Runner Game
I'm developing a 2D runner game using Kivy, and I'm implementing pixel-perfect collision detection. I used the keep_data = True property to enable access to the pixel data for my sprites, and the read_pixel() method to check for non-transparent pixels in overlapping regions.
Issue Description:

The collision detection works fine when the front of the character hits the front of the monster. The collision only triggers when their non-transparent pixels overlap, which is expected behavior (as shown in Image 1).
However, when the character jumps and lands on the back of the monster, the collision sometimes triggers even though their pixels don't actually touch, exactly when the bonding box of the character touch the pixel area of the monster (as shown in Image 2).

Image1
Image2
Code Overview:
Here’s the relevant part of my CollisionMixin class, which handles pixel-perfect collision detection:
class CollisionMixin:
    def collide_widget(self, other):
        # First, check if bounding boxes overlap
        if not super().collide_widget(other):
            return False

        # Get the overlapping area between the bounding boxes
        x1 = max(self.x, other.x)
        y1 = max(self.y, other.y)
        x2 = min(self.right, other.right)
        y2 = min(self.top, other.top)

        # Check pixel-perfect collision within the overlap
        for y in range(int(y1), int(y2)):
            for x in range(int(x1), int(x2)):
                # Ensure that both widgets have non-transparent pixels at the same point
                if self.pixel_collides_at(x, y) and other.pixel_collides_at(x, y):
                    return True
        return False

    def pixel_collides_at(self, x, y):
        """Check if the widget has a non-transparent pixel at (x, y)."""
        if not super().collide_point(x, y):
            return False

        # Convert to local coordinates of the widget
        x_local = int(x - self.x)
        y_local = int(self.height - (y - self.y))

        # Check if the pixel at (x_local, y_local) is non-transparent
        try:
            color = self._coreimage.read_pixel(x_local, y_local)
            return color[3] > 0  # Check alpha channel for transparency
        except:
            return False

Here code snippets of the character and monster:
class Character(CollisionMixin, Image):
    """
    some properties
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Character, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, .18)
        self.fit_mode = 'contain'
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.idle_frames = [f'assets/cat/idle/Idle_{i:02d}.png' for i in range(20)]
        self.run_frames = [f'assets/cat/run/Run_{i:02d}.png' for i in range(30)]
        self.jump_frames = [f'assets/cat/jump/Jump_{i:02d}.png' for i in range(20)]
        self.source = self.idle_frames[0]
        self.keep_data = True
        self.current_animation = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_idle_frame, 0.05)
        self.ground_y = Window.height * 0.09

    def start_running(self):
        self.stop_current_animation()
        self.current_animation = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_running_frame, 0.029)
       
    def stop_current_animation(self):
        if self.current_animation:
            self.current_animation.cancel()
            self.frame_index = 0
            self.current_animation = None
           
    def update_running_frame(self, dt):
        self.frame_index = (self.frame_index + 1) % len(self.run_frames)
        self.source = self.run_frames[self.frame_index]
       
    """
    Other functions for idle and jump movement, and jump logic
    """

class MonsterOne(CollisionMixin, Image):
    """
    some properties
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MonsterOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, .1)
        self.fit_mode = 'contain'
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.walk_frames = [f'assets/monster1/Walk_{i:02d}.png' for i in range(20)]
        self.source = self.walk_frames[0]
        self.keep_data = True
        self.current_animation = self.start_walking()
       
    def start_walking(self):
        self.stop_current_animation()
        self.current_animation = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_walk_frame, 0.05)
       
    def stop_current_animation(self):
        if self.current_animation:
            self.current_animation.cancel()
            self.frame_index = 0
            self.current_animation = None
       
    def update_walk_frame(self, dt):
        self.frame_index = (self.frame_index + 1) % len(self.walk_frames)
        self.source = self.walk_frames[self.frame_index]
       
    """
    Function to handle movement
    """

Here is the code of the function that update the game in the GameScreen:
class GameScreen(Screen):
    monsters = ListProperty([])
    .
    .
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update_event = None
       
    def start(self):
        .
        .
        .
        self.update_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)
       
    def update(self, dt):
        # Logics for generating and moving monster
       
               
        for monster in self.monsters:
            # Check for pixel collision
            if self.ids.character.collide_widget(monster):
                print('Pixel-perfect collision detected!')
                # Stop the current animation and movement for the character and the monster
                self.ids.character.stop_current_animation()
                monster.stop_current_animation()  

I've Tried:
Bounding Box Check: I verified that the bounding box check works properly—collision is only detected when the bounding boxes overlap.
Pixel Collision Check: I’m using read_pixel() to determine if there are non-transparent pixels in the overlapping region. This works most of the time, but there seems to be an issue when the character lands on the back of the monster.
